# Volume not mounting properly when running shell inside a container

Tags: docker

I want to encrypt my Kubernetes file to integrate it with Travis CI and for that, I am installing Travis CI CLI via docker container. When the container runs and I mount my current working directory to `/app` It just creates an empty folder.

I have added the folder in shared folders as well in the Virtual Box but nothing seems to work. I am using Docker Toolbox on Windows 10 home.

```
docker run -it -v ${pwd}:/app ruby:2.3 sh
```

It creates the empty app folder along with the other folders in the container but does not mount the volumes.

I also tried using

```
 docker run -it -v //c/complex:/app ruby:2.3 sh
```

as someone suggested to use the name you specify in the Virtual Box.

Answer (score 0):

Docker run -it -v full path of current directory:/app ruby:2